# IDFA looks like sent but nothing show up on Google Analytics Demographic Info

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, idfa

I want to implement iOS App Install Tracking to track my campaigns. It looks like a simple job but It doesn't work for me. I searched for below posts but nothing worked for me.

[How to detect an iOS app install campaign inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252203/how-to-detect-an-ios-app-install-campaign-inside-the-app)

[Google Analytics - iOS Install Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136199/google-analytics-ios-install-tracking)

First I create an URL with URL Builder then I open it on Safari. After It redirect me to the AppStore, I run the project from Xcode to the device (which doesn't have any app now). I can't see any campaigns below iTunes section in analytics. Even I can't see any demographic Information.  I enabled

```
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

and add iAd.framework and libAdIdAccess.a. When I debug the app with below code;

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
```

I can see devices &idfa on debug console. My question is that what am I doing wrong? I think that after I see demographics, everything will be solved.